# How to check the version of the SDK I am using?

Tags: iphone, target, operating-system

I dont know for which iPhone OS I am compiling my code, 3.0 or 2.2...

Comment: Do you really think that coding is what you should be doing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your target in your build config in xCode.

Comment: Thank You! I set the active SDK from iPhone Simulator 2.2 to iPhone Simulator 3.0

Answer (score 0):

```
 #ifdef __IPHONE_3_0
   NSLog(@"THE 3.0 SDK");
 #endif
```